# Selenium and Python - get next parent sibling

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm scraping a job board using Selenium. In the "job summary" section, all informations are not mandatory, which means that using XPath, if an information (e.g salary) is missing, the next information will be stored in this place.

I am trying to use the emojis before every information to check what information it is. The problem I have now is that the text related to the emoji is stored in the parent's next sibling, and I'm not able to retrieve it. Here's the html:

```
<li class="sc-16yjgsd-0 haea-DT">
<span role="img" class="sc-16yjgsd-1 cnWfGH">
<i class="sc-ACYlI bCYQRQ  wui-icon-font" name="salary"></i></span>
<span class="sc-16yjgsd-3 bCCdzk">Salaire entre 40,5K&nbsp;€ et 46K&nbsp;€</span></li>
```

And here is my latest try :

```
jobinfos = {"salary": [], "location": [], 'contract' : [], 'contract' : [], 'suitcase' : []}
for i in links[0:4]:
    driver.get(i)
    jobsummary = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prc-1-1-1']/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul")
    emoji_elements = jobsummary.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[1]/i")
    print("Number of emoji elements found:", len(emoji_elements))
    
    for emoji_element in emoji_elements:
        emoji_type = emoji_element.get_attribute("name")
        print(emoji_type)
        info_element = emoji_element.find_element_by_xpath("..//i[@name='{}']/following-sibling::i").format(emoji_type)
        info = info_element.text
        jobinfos[emoji_type].append(info)
```

which returns that it is unable to locate the following sibling.

Comment: What's the jobsboard url?

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: Here is the error I get : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"..//i[@name='{}']/following-sibling::span"}
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.119)